# Is generating a unique token enough to authenticate?

Tags: authentication

We're building a physical device. This device needs to communicate with a remote server. To this end, the device first sends a HTTP request (secured by SSL) to "register" the device with the server, which responds with a long, unique string token generated by a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator (CSPRNG), which in turn is associated with that device. The token is transferred back to the device via a SSL connection. The device then includes this token along with other identifying characteristics (such as a MAC address and IP address) via a SSL connection when sending requests.

Is this sufficiently enough to determine that the communicating device is who it says it is? Because all requests go through a SSL connection, a hacker would not be able to easily steal the token, correct? A hacker would need to acquire the physical device in order to extract the token, but each device has a unique token, so theft does not affect the functionality of other devices in the system.

Comment: Is it a problem in your scenario that according to your description not only the device can get a unique token but the attacker too and then use this attacker specific token in future communication?

Comment: All MAC addresses of the devices are stored in a database, so the attacker would need to acquire a valid MAC first, and then query the server to register a spoofed device. However, the device once registered needs to be "linked" to a valid user account, so even if the attacker spoofs a device, he can't do much with it as the attacker will have no access to another user's account.

Comment: The token is generated only on the server, and only the device and server should know what the token is.

Comment: What prevents an attacker simply guessing a valid MAC (especially if you buy a big batch of sequentially numbered NICs from one company), registering it to obtain a token, then doing whatever?

Comment: How does the sever decide if the connecting device is allowed to be registered? I feel like MAC and/or IP address are not secure enough for this, as they can both be spoofed.

Comment: All excellent points... What if I generate a unique token for each device during the manufacturing process and write it into the firmware, so that they not only need the correct MAC, but they also need the token to register? Then it'll be practically impossible to guess the "hardware token" for a valid MAC, so impossible to spoof someone else's device, correct? They can spoof their own device that they own physically, but each device is paired with a user account anyway, so they'd have to pair with their own account.

Comment: And combining that with the dynamically generated software token, i.e. checking the MAC, the H/W token and the S/W (server-assigned) token to authorize API calls? That way, if they sell the device to someone else, they can't use a spoofed MAC and extracted H/W token alone to spoof the device.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this solution is appropriate depends on a couple of factors.  As pointed out in comments the challenge with your outlined solution is that assuming an attacker can reach the service endpoint, they can complete the registration process and obtain valid tokens for use.

- Will the service accept registration from any MAC address or just ones which you know belong to valid devices?  If the range accepted is limited it might be more difficult for an attacker to discover a valid address to make the request?
- Will your service have any counter-measures against brute-force attacks?  Assuming the attacker can get the OUI for the MAC addresses you're using, they could cycle that space trying to get valid tokens.  In this scenario brute-force protections could help.
- What security assertion are you looking to use this token for?  If you're just pairing a user with a device and then using it to stop the user logging in to multiple devices, then this could work to an extent, although there is a risk that the user could copy the token to another device and change the MAC address to match the original.

Comment: Excellent points. Let me discuss these with my coworkers, thank you!